# NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I am getting an error while running a code in TensorFlow for data pre-processing.

```
NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\353\tensorflow_datasets\mnist\1.0.0\mnist-train.tfrecord-00005-of-00010 : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

Comment: did you found a solution? stubbled upon the same problem